# How can i change html tag dynamically? jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add paginate(page numbering) in my bulltin board;

this is the ui tag

```
<!-- UI Object -->
<div class="paginate_complex">
    <a href="#" class="direction prev"><span></span><span></span> First</a>
    <a href="#" class="direction prev"><span></span> prev</a>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
    <a href="#">4</a>
    <a href="#"><strong>5</strong></a>
    <a href="#">6</a>
    <a href="#">7</a>
    <a href="#">8</a>
    <a href="#">9</a>
    <a href="#" class="direction next">next<span></span></a>
    <a href="#" class="direction next">end <span></span><span></span></a>
</div>
```

Have to do this kind of stuff

1. add strong tag dynamically in the current page number
2. change the values of the numbers(for example, if the user presses next 1~9 changes to 11~19)
3. href value has to be changed if the user goes to next

and etc.

what kind of methods should i have to use in jQuery or javascript?

Comment: why those empty `span`?

Comment: The `href` should change to what?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Clarify point `2` and `3`.

Comment: @Alvaro - I'm guessing they're supposed to contain `<<`, `<`, `>` and `>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

- `.wrap('<strong/>')` to wrap an element in `strong` tags (kinda obvious)
- `.attr('href', data)` to modify the href or any other attribute.
- `.html(data)` to modify html contents (such as numbers)
- `.css(attr, value)` can be used to alter styling directly (instead of `.wrap()`)

But I'm not so sure if you want to do it directly like that. I'd probably create a function the generates the entire pagination html from scratch and re-renders the entire thing...

Answer (score 0):

To do bold you could do:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
$(this).css('font-weight', 'bold');
});
```

For change you could do:

```
$('.next').click(function(){
$('.content1').css({'content' : @'10'});
$('.content2').css({'content' : @'11'});
// etc...
});
```